# Accordion menu and IE7+ problem

Tags: html-lists, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-accordion

```
jQuery.noConflict(); 
(function($){
    $(function(){
         $("#jv_amenu_side49").accordion({     

             initShow : "ul.current",
             objClass:".jv_maccordion",
             slide:1             });
    }); })(jQuery);      (function($){
    $(function(){
         $("#jv_amenu_side49").aMenuLoad({
             activeItemId:1,
             moduleId:49,
            eventType:1             
    }); });          })(jQuery);
```

---

Opera Firefox Chrome - all work is good but 
IE 7 and IE 9 
have an error `Char:4 Error: Object doesnt support this property or method Code:0` at this line: `initShow : "ul.current"`,

i think it is UL tag but dont have an idea how to do it workable
[there is a left column menu](http://autojp.su)

Comment: Are you able to show us your HTML code? Maybe you could make a reproducable error on www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Also, what accordion plugin are you using? I don't see those options in the jQuery UI Accordion plugin...

Comment: @dtbarne: Please note as we have no idea what's going on at this point, those funky CDATA and comment tags you've edited out might actually be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Tough to see. You should past the HTML code that is relevant as well.

Anyway, are you sure you don't want initShow to be "li.current" or "ul .current"? Doesn't look right how you have it now, because that implies that the `ul` has a class of `.current`.

Comment: this is a joomla module menu - JV_accordion_menu